# How to find all strings in the Series- Data Science

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have the following problem. I have a salary file in San Francisco. In the BasePay column I want to count an average value. However, I have a few strings in the column and I can't count anything. Is there any possibility to find all the strings in a column at once? I have no idea how to get rid of strings or convert them to numbers.

Comment: Do you have any code or attempts we could look at?

Comment: One, you could loop over the column and get rid of strings by replacing them. Two, you could loop over the column to get all the non-string values and find their average.

Answer (score 0):

If your column has mixed types, it has an object dtype. This is just as slow as looping through a vanilla python list. Also, how are you handling the strings? Can they be converted to numeric values or are they just invalid entries? If they're invalid, they probably shouldn't count towards the cardinality of the column. Post a sample of your data if you want better help.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'salary':[60_000, 50_000, 'NA', 40_000]})

total = 0
n = 0
for s in df.salary:
    try:
        # should only work for numeric values
        total+=s
        n+=1
    except:
        pass
average = total / n
print(average)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to filter out all the times that salary is a string and then do the average:

```py
df[~(df["salary"].map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)))].mean()
```